# Есть ли на данный момент реализация MediaRecorder API в nodejs?

Tags: node.js, webrtc, mediarecorder

Есть ли на данный момент реализация MediaRecorder API в nodejs? Или придется самому все собирать из исходников подключив потом с помощью "native modules"? Если так, прошу подсказать насколько это трудозатратно

Answer (score 0):

Да, есть. Заходите в `npm.com` и ищите `MediaRecorder`. Вам выпадет 41 результат. Выбирайте любую.

- https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=MediaRecorder
- https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=keywords:mediarecorder

Comment: Все результаты client-side`овские, которые являются обертками для нативного MediaRecorder. Мне нужно решение для nodejs)